# Impossible comparison between ulong and long suddenly possible

Tags: c#, casting, long-integer, comparison-operators

I know why this is not allowed:

```
ulong x = 0xFEDCBA9876543210;
long y = Int64.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(x < y);
```

Obviously, there is no way for the runtime to implicitly cast either operand to the other type or a larger type to make the comparison work.

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'long'.

So, this is also not allowed (with `MinValue` and `const`):

```
ulong x = 0xFEDCBA9876543210;
const long y = Int64.MinValue;
Console.WriteLine(x < y);
```

Yet, this is allowed (with `MaxValue` instead):

```
ulong x = 0xFEDCBA9876543210;
const long y = Int64.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(x < y);
```

There is no overload of `<` accepting a `ulong` and `long`, but I saw with Reflector that this will silently convert `Int64.MaxValue` to a `ulong`. But this does not always happen. How does it work, and what considerations are the reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: If you change it to use `Int64.MinValue`, the second one does _not_ compile

Comment: @PaulPhillips Quite correct and it makes sense since the constant `Int64.MinValue` does not fall within the valid range of `ulong` whereas the constant `Int64.MaxValue` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One big difference between `long y = Int64.MaxValue; if (x < y)...` and `if (x < Int64.MaxValue)` is that in the latter case the compiler can actually see the constant value if it desired to.  It can see that the actual constant value fits in the ulong range and therefore an implicit cast is ok.

For a plain variable `long y`, the compiler can't make any assumptions about what the runtime value of y is. Nevermind that the assignment statement is just one statement up; the compiler doesn't keep track of values assigned to variables.

As noted by DarkGray, a const var behaves as a constant since you have told the compiler that its value will never change.

Answer (score 1):

Const long with value in ulong range silently converts to const ulong.

This is allowed:

```
ulong x = 0xFEDCBA9876543210; 
const long y = Int64.MaxValue; 
Console.WriteLine(x < y); 

const ulong z = y;
```